# Deploy and connect build application into Bluemix PaaS?

Tags: database, eclipse, ibm-cloud

I already deploy my application with eclipse and built in database (generated from AssestDB of the application). I want now to manage the application and deploy it with IBM bluemix PaaS, to manage Mobile Data.

What is the best DB I must use when coding before deploy into Bluemix?

Comment: You might want to be a bit more specific in your question

Answer (score 4):

If you want to configure your local test environment in order to minimize migration problems when deploying your application on Bluemix, you should replicate the target environment on your local one, as much as possible.

If you are planning to use the Mobile Data service on Bluemix please consider that it is built on Cloudant NOSQL Database, and it offers a further layer of abstraction that allows you to directly persist objects (if you are familiar with the concepts of class, object etc..).

You could also directly connect from a local application to a DB service instance running on Bluemix.